# How to generate entities from one file YAML in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, yaml, php-5.3, mysql-workbench

I have plugin to MySQL Workbench, which generate YAML file.

In doctrine 1.2, I use

```
Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml('1.yml', $models_dir, $options);
```

and PHP models are created.
It is possible to make the same process in Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more reliable solution for generating your YML (or XML or annotations) Doctrine2 files, you can take a look at [Skipper](http://www.skipper18.com) application.

It's a visual modeler for ORM frameworks (Doctrine, Doctrine2, MongoDB ODM, ...) with schema definition import/export support.